# convert log data into delimited text file using shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

i want to convert data (log file) the below data using unix shell script
from

```
key1=value1|key2=value2|key3=value3

key1=value1|key2=value2|key3=value3

key1=value1|key2=value2|key4=value4

key1=value1|key2=value2|key5=value5

key1=value1|key2=value2|key3=value3
```

to (delimited text file)

```
key1|key2|key3|key4|key5

value1|value2|value3||

value1|value2|value3||

value1|value2||value4|

value1|value2|||value5   

value1|value2|value3||
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use bash, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define headline
headline="key1|key2|key3|key4|key5"

# split headline into separat entries
readarray -d '|' header <<< "$headline"

# get last fieldnr in array
lastfieldnr=$((${#header[@]} - 1))

# write headline to output
echo "$headline"

# loop over all entry lines
while read -r line; do

   # separate key=value pairs
   readarray -d '|' key_value <<< "$line"

   # define associative array
   declare -A content

   # loop over key=value pairs
   for kv in "${key_value[@]}"; do

      # split key value pair in separate fields
      # strip last |
      IFS='=' read -r key value <<< "${kv%|}"

      # save result in associative array
      content[$key]="$value"
   done  

   # initialize output
   output=""

   # loop over all fields
   for i in $(seq 0 $lastfieldnr); do

      # get length of key
      length="${#header[$i]}"

      # strip last character from key
      key="${header[$i]:0:$length - 1}"

      # if content[$key] not empty
      if [ -n "${content[$key]}" ]; then

         # get value
         value="${content[$key]}"

         # append value to output
         output+="$value"
      fi

      # append | at end of output
      output+="|"
   done

   # complete line to output, strip last |
   printf "%s\n" "${output%|}"

   # delete associateive array
   unset content
done < file.log
```

**input (file.log)**

```
key1=value1|key2=value2|key3=value3
key1=value1|key2=value2|key3=value3
key1=value1|key2=value2|key4=value4
key1=value1|key2=value2|key5=value5
key1=value1|key2=value2|key3=value3
```

**output**

```
key1|key2|key3|key4|key5
value1|value2|value3||
value1|value2|value3||
value1|value2||value4|
value1|value2|||value5
value1|value2|value3||
```

Comment: Thank you UtLox !! do you have any solution with awk ?